# php openssl: how to match the private key with the certificate

Tags: php, ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a self signed signature which contains the certificate itself and the private key. My purpose is to check if this private key matches with the certificate. What I do is the following:

```
$private = openssl_pkey_get_private("path/to/certificate");
$public  = openssl_pkey_get_public("path/to/certificate");
openssl_sign("path/to/certificate", $sig, $private);
```

So I create the signature based on the private and the public keys from the file. So what I need to do is to compare this signature with the existing signature in the certificate. If they match, it means that the private key matches. However, I couldn't retrieve the existing signature information from the file. I was wondering if my way is a right way to do it since I have found no information on google.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a self signed signature which contains the certificate itself and the private key. My purpose is to check if this private key matches with the certificate. What I do is the following:

Certificates don't contain private keys. Just public keys. They're signed by a private key (which in the case of self-signed certs would be the private key corresponding to the public key contained in the cert) but they do not contain private keys.

> So what I need to do is to compare this signature with the existing signature in the certificate. If they match, it means that the private key matches.

They shouldn't ever match. Check out [phpseclib's X.509 parser](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/decoder.php) and decode the sample cert they provide with it. There are three parts at the root level. tbsCertificate, signatureAlgorithm and signature. signature is based on tbsCertificate. So you're wanting a signature of tbsCertificate to match a signature of all three fields combined. Which is pretty much never going to happen.

As for extracting the signature itself... you can use phpseclib for that. eg.

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509('...');

echo $cert['signature']
```

Answer (score 6):

If all you want to do is check if the private key and the certificate matches, you can just call `openssl_x509_check_private_key`. It takes a certificate and private key as input and returns whether they both match or not. Take a look at the documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-check-private-key.php).

**EDIT**: Also, note that, the signature in the certificate is arrived using different information that composes the certificate whereas the data that you pass to the openssl_sign function is just the path to the certificate. So, even if you do end up identifying a way to extract the signature from the certificate, it still won't match the output of openssl_sign (definitely not with the $data that you are passing to openssl_sign).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to do "real" check. I want to compare the signatures but I couldn't extract the signature information out from the certificate file. Do you have any idea how I can retrieve it?

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way in PHP OpenSSL to retrieve the signature information from the certificate file. The closest you can get is openssl_x509_parse to get information from a certificate. But, even that doesn't retrieve the signature. If you are okay to experiment by parsing the certificate yourself, then take a look at http://bit.ly/17ZIdwC. Function ``extractSignature`` might be helpful. But, it expects a DER encoded certificate.

Comment: Ok then I will use openssl_x509_check_private_key function in case of self signed certificates. However, how should I check the match if user provides intermediate certificate and the real certificate?

Comment: If you are given an intermediate certificate and end-entity certificate from another user, you probably won't have their private keys to do any matching.  You might have a trusted certificate or public key corresponding to the CA that signed the intermediate certificate, and you can use those to verify the signature on the intermediate certificate, and then use the intermediate certificate to verify the signature of the end-entity certificate.

Answer (score 1):

@Karthik:

many thanks for your pointer to http://badpenguins.com/source/misc/isCertSigner.php?viewSource . It is a pity, that openssl-php library lacks the **extractSignature** function.

I added the code found on http://badpenguins.com/source/misc/isCertSigner.php to

- my simple certificate viewer (PHP) https://github.com/Wikinaut/MySimpleCertificateViewer .